# Return to node.js socket and cURL it with PHP

Tags: php, node.js, curl, socket.io

I am sending a steamid to node.js via curl and want to process it then.

But I am stuck at sending/retrieving an response...

Just as an ex. if the steamid can be processed -> then display return the processed value back to php.

app.js:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server)

server.listen(1777);

function handler(req, res) {
    switch(req.url) {
        case '/push':

        if (req.method == 'POST') {
            var request = '';

            req.on('data', function(chunk) {
                request += chunk.toString();
            });

            req.on('end', function() {
                var json = JSON.parse(request);
                console.log(json.steamid);

                io.sockets.emit('push', { message: json.steamid });
                res.end();
            });
        }

        break;
  };
};
```

php:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('steamid' => '76561141654816854');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:1777/push");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_exec($ch);
```